# Click Tracking with Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```html
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function (url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
      'hitCallback': function () {
         document.location = url;
      }
   });
}
</script>

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Hi, I have tried to adding the above on my site for tracking links from various sources. But I am not able to see any clicks in analytics.

Although Jetpack is showing links to that url.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
        'transport': 'beacon',
        'hitCallback': function(){
            document.location = url;
        }
    });
}
```